# How to get button title?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im trying to get my button name , from the event, but I'm not finding it

my button call(JSX) code:

```
   {...}
 <View style={styles.container}> 
    {userForm.map((item) => (       
      <Button title = {item.name.slice(7)} key = {item.info.uuid} onPress = {handleClick} />    
    ))}
    
    </View>
      {...}
```

My handle click constant where I try to get the button title:

```
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    var objeto = e.currentTarget.title;
    console.log(objeto);

    };
```

someone knows where or how to get my button title ?

Comment: `Button` needs a `name` prop for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.currentTarget` gives you the button element that is rendered in your screen. You could access its text content by using `e.currentTarget.textContent` or you can pass the title as an argument directly to your `handleClick` function:

```
<Button title = {item.name.slice(7)} key = {item.info.uuid} onPress = {handleClick(item.name.slice(7))} />


  const handleClick = (buttonTitle) => (e) => {
    console.log(buttonTitle)
    };
```

Comment: I tried to put `e.currentTarget.textContent` but it returns me an undefined , and the other example worked pretty fine thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `objeto` to `var objeto = e.currentTarget.title;`

You're setting `title` on the component but trying to read `name` on your handleClick.